# rdflib::as_rdf only recognizes some IRIs

Tags: r, rdf, redland

I am trying to convert a dataframe to RDF. The dataframe contains literals as well as IRIs.

I'm doing

```
test_withangles.rdf <-
  rdflib::as_rdf(x = test_withangles,
                 key = 'uuid')
rdf_serialize(rdf = test_withangles.rdf, doc = "test_withangles.ttl")
```

on

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| uuid                                 | source_ontology                               | source_term                                          |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| 7ca250c1-0747-4db0-b613-a1bb45848711 | <http://192.168.0.233:8080/ontologies/RXNORM> | <http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/706898> |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| e10acb95-e9d9-4804-a227-844f3e551c78 | <http://192.168.0.233:8080/ontologies/RXNORM> | <http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/214081> |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

and getting

```
@base <localhost://> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<df:7ca250c1-0747-4db0-b613-a1bb45848711>
    <df:source_ontology> <http://192.168.0.233:8080/ontologies/RXNORM> ;
    <df:source_term> "<http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/706898>" .

<df:e10acb95-e9d9-4804-a227-844f3e551c78>
    <df:source_ontology> <http://192.168.0.233:8080/ontologies/RXNORM> ;
    <df:source_term> "<http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/214081>" .
```

Why is it interpreting my `source_term` column as strings, instead of IRIs?

Comment: Hi @mark-miller, can you please un-tag this with "rdflib"? From that tag's notes: "RDFLib is a Python library for working with RDF.". This is about R (which you've also tagged) but the "rdflib" tag put it on the wrong people's radar. Thanks.

Comment: @NicholasCar that was very diplomatically written and motivated me to look at the dependencies of R's rdflib more closely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example